# Does loading a page into physical memory for the first time cause a major page fault?

Tags: c, malloc, posix, virtual-memory

Let's say we have a process A, that's just been created that does an allocation of SIZE bytes.

e.g.

```c
ptr = malloc( SIZE )
```

I know that this buffer will be reserved in the virtual process space of the process, my question is : will we get major page faults the FIRST time we write into this buffer, and if so why ?

Update : This was done on ArchLinux using gcc.

Comment: Page faults occur when data on the page in question is not already mapped to physical memory. The memory block you allocated may however reside on the same page as some other memory block that you previously allocated and accessed, and then there would be no page fault.

Comment: This is OS-dependent, but you haven't specified your OS.  Even if it is allocated on a brand-new page from the OS, some might prefault the page into memory before you write to it, others might not.  But either way it should not be a major page fault as nothing has to be loaded from disk; we just have to update the page tables to point at an available physical memory page.  That should be a minor fault.

Comment: It depends on the implementation. For glibc, `malloc` uses `mmap` for large allocations, but there will be some meta-data at the start of the first page with the returned pointer being the address after the meta-data. So the first "page size minus metadata size" bytes of returned memory will have been already paged in at least once by the time `malloc` returns. Oh, and as @NateEldredge writes, it will be a minor fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will we get major page faults the FIRST time we write into this buffer, and if so why ?

You might or might not get one normal page fault for the first write.

It depends on which OS (and which implementation of `malloc()`); but I'd expect that (for most operating systems and most implementations of `malloc()`):

- the `malloc()` causes virtual pages to be created, where those virtual pages are the same physical page full of zeros mapped many times at many virtual addresses as "read only" (it's a little bit like using mirrors to make it look like a single banana is a room full of bananas).
- when you write to one of the pages for the first time, you get one page fault, and the OS allocates a new physical page, fills it with zeros, and maps it at the appropriate address in the virtual address space as "read/write" (replacing the old "read only" page full of zeros).
- this probably happens for each individual virtual page (e.g. writing to one virtual page won't cause any other virtual page to become allocated or "read/write"). However, an OS may (if there's lots of spare RAM, and/or if the OS detected an easily predicted "sequential write" pattern), pre-allocate physical pages before you write to them (to avoid future page faults); and an OS may decide to use a different/larger page size (e.g. instead of allocating a 4 KiB page it might allocate a 2 MiB "large page" instead).
- for some implementations of `malloc()` (and some values of `SIZE`), some of the virtual memory may already be allocated and mapped during `malloc()` (e.g. because `malloc()` wrote a header at the start of the allocated block and caused the page fault itself).
- you may get more page faults later (e.g. if you have one page fault on the first write that allocates the page; then data in the allocated page may be sent to swap space to free the physical page later, and then subsequent reads or writes will cause more page faults to fetch the data from swap space).

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, this clarifies things !